# Nodejs find array property value based on value of another property

Tags: node.js, arrays, postgresql, find

I am having trouble finding the value of a property in an array based on the value of another property. I am trying to assign the variable x with the value of sensors.type when searching for a specific sensorID.  For example in the table below if I have the value of the sensor ID (yellow box) I am trying to assign the value of the type (red box) to the variable x.

I load an array 'sensors' with data from a PostgreSQL database with the following code:

```
var sensors = [];

var pgp = require('pg-promise')(options);
var connection = "postgres://xxxxxxx:yyyyyyy@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/heatmap"
var db = pgp(connection);

getSensors();
setInterval(getSensors,10000)

function getSensors(){
    var q = "select * from sensors order by id"
    db.query(q)
    .then(function (data) {
        data.forEach((s)=>{
            sensors[s.mac.trim()] = s
            console.log(s)
        })
    }, function (reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.err("Query error, "+error);
    });   

}
```

when I run the command console.table(sensors) this is what I see ..

[image: Output of console.table(sensors)]

Also I can see details for each record with console.dir(sensors) ...

[image: Output of console.dir(sensors)]

I have an input string which I parse to get the sensorId I want to search the array for and can verify it exists with a valid value via console.log output.

```
var sensorId = rawData.substring(6,18);
var sensorRecord = sensors[sensorId];
```

[image: Shows the sensorID I am searching for and the array record found]

I cannot seem to find a way of searching the array for the sensorType and assigning the value of the associated 'type' from the array to a variable.

I thought the following would:

```
var sensorType = sensors[sensorId].type;
```

But it returns the following error:

[image: Error returned from sensorId find attempt]

Would appreciate any help and guidance.

Comment: Looking to see if anyone has ideas on this issue or if additional details are required that I did not provide?